How Process of Khula Is Done As per Fuqaha
There is a lot of debate over social media that if a women want to separate from husband then she can take Khula. Some say just give back mahr and your Khula is done. Some say visit Qaadhi or Imam (in case of living in Dar Al Kufr] he will look into matter and decide.
But all of this becoming confusion in matter of Khula because we approach Qaadhi or Imam than that is process to make Nikah Fasqh not Khula. So what is the right way Khula as per Fuqaha
